# How to move one image to another imageview with position changing animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an image in a collection view, I want to move collection view image when I click on a cell that image move to imageview with animation.

I tried CABasicAnimation function but it couldn't work.

I tried to change x and y frame but that's not taking perfect cell frames.

I am trying using dummy frame but that's also not working.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, animations: {
//FIND VIEW FROM MAIN VIEW
            if let oriView = self.viewCollection.viewWithTag(567){
//DUMY FRAME WHICH ADD ON COLLECTION CELL
                self.dumy.frame = CGRect(x: oriView.frame.origin.x, y: oriView.frame.origin.y, width: oriView.frame.size.width, height: oriView.frame.size.height)
                self.dumy.image = UIImage(named: "abc")
                self.dumy.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                self.dumy.clipsToBounds = false
                self.viewCollection.addSubview(self.dumy)
            }
        }, completion: { done in
            //IMAGEVIEW AT TOP OF SCREEN
            self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "abc")
            self.imgView.layer.borderColor = myColors.AppBorder.cgColor
            self.imgView.clipsToBounds = true
        })
```

[image]

I want to move collectionview cell image move to the top four imageview when it's clicked.
Please help me out, how's to take cell frame or change position of the image with animation of moving.

Comment: Share GIF for animation.

Comment: Can you please share visuals for animation output?

Comment: `imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xValue, y: yValue)`

Comment: imgView.transform is not works, i have to move collection view cell image to imageview.

Comment: Are you using a custom cell or a regular `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: i am using custom cell.

Comment: Take screenshot of cell and animate that image to the frames u wanted, then on completion you can set image in new view.This will give u exact effect u wanted.
Remove screenshot in order to take good care of memory.